# Arduino Micro interference between analog inputs

Tags: analogread, arduino-micro

I'm building a MIDI controller with the Arduino Micro, hooking a bunch of knobs up to the analog inputs. Currently, I'm getting analog in 9 being influenced by analog in 10: `analogRead(9)` returns a number close to `analogRead(10)` and doesn't give the voltage that I'm reading with a multimeter.

What could be causing this interference?

Answer (score 2):

I looked around for a while and eventually thought to put the multimeter probe on the top pin instead of on the soldered header, and got no voltage across it.

If you're experiencing a strange interference between two analog inputs, double-check your solder joints again, one of your inputs might be floating (not connected to high or ground).